# Python convert from number system to number system

Tags: python, numbers, system

in class we got the Task to programm a script to convert from number systems to number systems (like from hex to dual etc).
I dont expect full codes, just want to show mine, it works but i feel like its bad (we only had python for 3 weeks).
Any suggestions to improve it?
Like i said, homework is done and already turned in, but i want to improve ;)

```
       if aw == "q" or aw == "1" or aw == "2" or aw == "3" or aw == "4":
            done = False
        else:
            print("\n Keine gültige Auswahl bitte versuchen Sie es erneut ")
    
    return aw

def ag(blacklist):              
    done = True
    while done:
        
        if blacklist !="1":
            print ("(d) Dezimal")
        if blacklist !="2":
            print ("(b) Binär")
        if blacklist !="3":
            print ("(h) Hexadezimal")
        if blacklist !="4":
            print ("(o) Oktal")
        if blacklist !="q":
            print ("(q) Beenden")
            
        print ("")

    
        ag = input("Ihre Wahl")
        if ag == "d" or ag == "b" or ag == "h" or ag == "o" or ag == "q":
            done = False
        else:
            
            print("\n Keine gültige Auswahl bitte versuchen Sie es erneut ")
        return ag
def convertToOctal(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(oct(decimal))[2:]

def convertToHex(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(hex(decimal))[2:]

def convertToBinary(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(bin(decimal))[2:]

def convertToDecimal(number, base, validBases = [2, 8, 16]):
    """
      Returns the number (given in string format) in the specified base
    """
    if base not in validBases:
        raise Exception("Invalid base")
        
    return int(number, base)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are learning Python for 3 weeks, you did well. You just have to learn the built-in functions already in Python and how they work.

```py
def convertToOctal(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(oct(decimal))[2:]

def convertToHex(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(hex(decimal))[2:]

def convertToBinary(decimal):
    # slice off the first two characters and return the rest
    return str(bin(decimal))[2:]

def convertToDecimal(number, base, validBases = [2, 8, 16]):
    """
      Returns the number (given in string format) in the specified base
    """
    if base not in validBases:
        raise Exception("Invalid base")
        
    return int(number, base)
```

You also have to do some error checking (e.g. whether the user actually passed in a valid number to the appropriate function), but the above code is basically your business logic in the program.